# Compiz equivalent

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager

I am using Mint 14 Cinnamon and would like to install something similar to Compiz. I love to bind key shortcuts and mouse clicking to perform some frequently used actions. I know Compiz is unstable so any suggestion to an equivalent tool which is more stable? It would be great if the tool is made for Mint Cinnamon, but Im OK if it works with another window manager. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is one. What exactly are you trying to do? I have managed to replicate _most_ of my favorite compiz tricks with the latest cinnamon. What are you missing?

Comment: Hmm, how's about scrolling mouse up/down at the right screen edge to switch to next/previous workspace?